# Cant seem to fix Attribute error: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'

Tags: string, attributeerror

Here is my code:

```
def read_csv(file_name):
    data = file_name.read()
    split_data = data.split("\n")
    string_list = split_data[1:len(split_data)]
    final_list = []

    for x in string_list:
        int_fields = []
        string_fields = x.split(",")
        int_fields.append(int(string_fields)) # convert final list into an integer
        final_list.append(int_fields)
    return final_list 

cdc_list = read_csv("US_births_1994-2003_CDC_NCHS.CSV")

cdc_list[0:10]
```

It keeps telling me that `str` object has no attribute `read`.

How can I fix this error?

Comment: Is this python code? If so, it means that the variable file_name is a string (you should open the path/filename as a file)

Comment: If it bites like a snake....and spits back "Traecback errors"... it might be the beloved reptile...

Comment: ..confirmed... its pythonic **"AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'read'"**.

Answer (score 0):

A bit tricky without the rest of your code, but i'd guess, you're not handing over the proper object, but just the filename instead?